# Mongodb refusing to work with java project First time using Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently trying to learn how to use mongodb and I am stuck trying to call Mongoclient, I am using maven in order handle my imports(Also new to maven) Down below is my \

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Model m) {
    m.addAttribute("name", "Jhon smith");

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

    return "index";

}
```

Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient

Pom File dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe `mongo-java-driver` should be sufficient enough. You could get rid of `bson` and `mongodb-driver-core` dependency.

Comment: @nullpointer error persists unfortunately

Comment: How about `3.5.0` version of `mongo-java-driver`. When exactly does this error occur for you?

Comment: @nullpointer as soon as I call the method and it tries to run the code, also changing to 3.5 did not change anything

Comment: How are you launching your code? Is your IDE configured to properly use Maven and load all the dependency you defined? (such as m2e with Eclipse) Did you run mvn package or similar command to download all of your dependencies?

Comment: @PierreB. I am using intellj and it is loading the dependencies

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown at runtime, meaning you successfully compiled your code, but when you are trying to run it the JVM cannot find your class. IntelliJ seems to have indeed loaded the dependencies, but your issue may arise from the way you actually ran your code, hence my previous question: How are you running your code? Are you running it directly from IntelliJ? Using a java command from console?
Your issue may also arise from a configuration in your pom.xml, can you provide the entire pom?